# OSPF between Cisco and HP devices

Tags: cisco, ospf, hp

Does anyone have experience with creating HP and Cisco devices?  I created a simple OSPF config, but I can't see any neighbours.

Here is my basic config.

```
#
#HP 5500-48G-PoE+-4SFP HI Switch
#
router id 30.0.0.1
#
ospf 2
 area 0.0.0.0
  network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255
#
interface GigabitEthernet1/0/1
 port link-mode route
 ip address 30.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
#

#
#Cisco IOS Software, 2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 15.0(1)M7, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc2)
#
interface FastEthernet0/0
 ip address 20.0.0.1 255.0.0.0
 duplex auto
 speed auto
 !
#
router ospf 2
 router-id 20.0.0.1
 log-adjacency-changes
 network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255 area 0
#
```

Comment: I don't know HP that well, but on your Cisco router, if you type debug ip ospf adjacency, it will tell you why it's not forming a neighbor relationship.

Comment: *network 0.0.0.0 255.255.255.255* means no networks are included. (that's a netmask, not a wildcard)

Comment: @RickyBeam, the newer Cisco IOS version actually convert the mask to a wildcard mask for you for both OSPF and EIGRP. I'm not sure at what version the change was made, but it works. The Cisco code is obviously from before the change, based on the output.

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Bot devices must me on the same subnet if you want to communicate between then, if you have post here the configuration on the interfaces that are connected directly, i think, they cannot form adyacency.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you have different subnets on both devices. OSPF does subnet check while forming adjacency (exception are p2p links). Make sure both devices are on the same subnet.

You can always turn on debugs to check out what is going on:

> debug ip ospf hello
>
> debug ip ospf events
>
> debug ip ospf packet
>
> debug ip ospf adj